# How to run xhr request with address written in template

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I'm trying to run XHR request on URL that controller obtain from template.

I get url like this

Angular code:

```
ManageControllers.controller('ManageCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ManageCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $scope.urls = {
            edit : '',
            get : ''
        };

        $http.post($scope.urls.get).success(function(data) {
            $scope.recipe = data;
        });
    }
]);
```

HTML template:

```
<div ng-app="ManageApp">
    <div ng-controller="ManageCtrl">
        <input 
            ng-model="urls.save"
            ng-init="
                urls.save = '/save';
            "
        />
        <input
            ng-model="urls.get"
            ng-init="
                urls.get = '/get';
            "
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

So far Angular reads value from trmplate. But it looks like $http runs before ng-init. So I don't know if it is better to run $http from some function with timeout or there is some proper, angular way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code a bit without the need of a setTimeout :

```
<input
    ng-model="urls.get"
    ng-init="initGet('/get')"
 />


ManageControllers.controller('ManageCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ManageCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $scope.urls = {
            edit : '',
            get : ''
        };

        $scope.initGet = function(url) {
            $scope.urls.get = url;
            $http.post($scope.urls.get).success(function(data) {
                $scope.recipe = data;
            });
        };


    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks. That is great solution. Bu isn't there something more out of the box to trigger $http after ng-init ?

Comment: you could try with `$viewContentLoaded`. But the best solution would be to create a directive for your need, passing the url to a directive attribute and firing $http call in the link function

Comment: I have to make some research. Thanks for directions.